# Benefit of Asp.net core IMemoryCache

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to use a memory cache in asp.net core and I'm implementing cache as a Singleton service, now I see IMemoryCache builtin asp.net core.

Do I want to know what is the benefits of IMemoryCache asp.net core against my Singleton service?

Thanks for taking the time and share your ideas

Comment: And to add to the answer, as with any popular library, IMemoryCache is tried and tested by 1000s of developers and will be supported in the future. I'm not so sure about your singleton.

Comment: @StuartLC Of course, your right. I want to be sure to change my codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You dont need to handle synchronization of threads
2. SetSlidingExpiration is build in memory cache
3. RegisterPostEvictionCallback - callback if data are expired.
4. Limit size of cache
5. Testing, its much easier to inject and mock data then test with singleton.

You can read [all here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2) :)

Comment: Thanks, The only thing that came to my mind was services for testing.